# weighted graph traversal shortest path

Tags: c++, graph, traversal, depth-first-search

I'm trying to figure out this programming challenge that can be found [here](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&format=html&probid=110903). In the example, the author mention that the best route to take is 1-2-4-7. However, when we add up all the passengers it only comes out to 90... The author also mentions that it would take at least five trips to get all the passengers there. Yet when I add it up it seem like it would be more... For example, using the route the author said.

4 trips from 1-2 to get all 99 passengers there

4 trips from 2-4

3 trips from 4-7

Am I thinking about this completely wrong?

Comment: The most you can get across 1-2-4-7 in one run is 25 (2-4 is the limiting trip), so it takes 4 runs. You don't add the numbers, they represent the maximum number of people in the bus.

Comment: @Ourous Oh I see, since we're trying to move the maximum number of passengers per trip, we're looking at the lowest weight in each path... That makes perfect sense. However, shouldn't it just be 4 trips then?

Comment: The 25 people includes the tour guide (missed this earlier), so it's actually 24 per run, so 5 runs. Sorry about that :)